# Specify sysroot for Bazel toolchain

Tags: c++, bazel, toolchain

I'm using `cc_toolchain_config` from `unix_cc_toolchain_config.bzl` to configure my custom toolchain. I want to specify a custom sysroot, so I call:

```
cc_toolchain_config(
  #...
  cxx_builtin_include_directories = [
    "%sysroot%/usr/include",
  ],
)
```

Bazel complains:

```
A %sysroot% prefix is only allowed if the default_sysroot option is set
```

I could not find a reference to the "default_sysroot" option (I think the error message is wrong), but there's a "builtin_sysroot" option that [cc_native.create_cc_toolchain_config_info](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.23.0/skylark/lib/cc_common.html#create_cc_toolchain_config_info) uses. This is the function that `cc_toolchain_config` [actually uses](https://cs.opensource.google/bazel/bazel/+/master:tools/cpp/unix_cc_toolchain_config.bzl;l=1215;bpv=1;bpt=0), but it does not specify the `builtin_sysroot` argument directly. However, it [does configure](https://cs.opensource.google/bazel/bazel/+/master:tools/cpp/unix_cc_toolchain_config.bzl;l=228;bpv=1;bpt=0) a "sysroot" feature, but I have no idea how to use that. I tried `bazel build --features sysroot` as hinted by the [doc](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cc-toolchain-config-reference.html#features), but it gives the same error.

How to make `unix_cc_toolchain_config.bzl:cc_toolchain_config` use the sysroot I specify?

Comment: I opened an issue in the Bazel repository regarding the error message: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/16447

Answer (score 3):

As of [commit da345f1](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/da345f1f249ebf28bec88c6e0d63260dfaef14e9), `unix_cc_toolchain_config.bzl:cc_toolchain_config` has a `builtin_sysroot` attribute that can be used to configure the builtin sysroot:

```
cc_toolchain_config(
  #...
  cxx_builtin_include_directories = [
    "%sysroot%/usr/include",
  ],
  builtin_sysroot = "path/to/my/sysroot",
)
```